# Fully logged site Django

Tags: django, authentication

I use [django-stronghold](https://github.com/mgrouchy/django-stronghold)

too logged my site.

See my code:

## settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'stronghold',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'stronghold.middleware.LoginRequiredMiddleware',
)

STRONGHOLD_PUBLIC_URLS = (
    '/admin/',
)
```

## views.py

```
...
from stronghold.decorators import public
...

@public
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

@public
def about(request):
    return render(request, 'about.html')

class PersonList(ListView):
    pass

class PersonDetail(DetailView):
    pass

class PersonForm(CreateView):
    pass
```

## urls.py

```
...
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls), name='admin'),
```

But how do I **redirect** to the login page when I click on a link with login required? Redirect to /admin/

Because the remaining pages are returning 404 when not logged in.

Comment: Does adding `LOGIN_URL = '/admin/'` to `settings.py` do anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does adding `LOGIN_URL = '/admin/'` to *settings.py*.